# Curve sketching: if $\dot{x} = x- 2y-x^2$ , which is the dominant term?

Tags: functions, derivatives

$\dot{x} = x- 2y-x^2$

I am trying to find where $x$ increases or decreases.
I thought $x^2$ would be the dominant term because it has a high power however in my notes it says $-2y$ is the dominant term. Is there a way I can easily check this? Perhaps by plugging in different numbers?

Comment: It depends on location $(x,y)$. For $x>5$ and $-1<y<1$ one can easily show, that $|x-x^2| > 20 \gg 2 > |2y|$. Possible locations can be obtained or estimated from whole problem set-up including initial conditions and $\dot{y}(x,y,t)$.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you *mean* by the phrase “dominant term” in this context, to begin with. Could you perhaps elaborate? Also, can't you simply say that $\dot x > 0$ iff $x - 2y - x^2 > 0$ iff $y < \tfrac12 (x-x^2)$? (The region defined by that last inequality shouldn't be too hard to sketch.)